# ajax php foreach loop update after each iteration

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

What I am trying to do is is use jQuery/Ajax to make a request to a PHP script and return a status update each time the `foreach` loop completes. I want to use the output to make a progress bar.

The problem I am having is the jQuery will only update the page once the whole script has completed. Is there a way to force either the jQuery or PHP to output on every loop and not just dump all of it on `success` function.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {            
            $(document).on('click','#fetch-snowfall-data a',function () {
              $(this).text('Fetching Snowfall Data...');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: true,
                    url: "url.php",  
                    data:{},                
                    dataType: "html", 
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#response_container").append(response);
                        $('#fetch-snowfall-data a').text('Fetch Snowfall Data');
                    }
                }); 
            return false;
            });
        });
```

PHP

```
foreach ( $results['resorts'] as $resort ) {

    //Do all the things here

    $count++;
    echo $count .'/'. $results['total_rows'];

}
```

Comment: Not really, you'd probably need SSE, Sockets or do polling for that, you generally can't return partial content (but it is possible with flushing)

Comment: An easy solution would be add the `beforeSend:` attribute and put a function that will fill your container with a spinner gif or something so at least people will see it's doing something. You would need a more sophisticated jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139613/update-progress-bar-using-ajax-request-seconds for actual progress.

Comment: @Rasclatt I tried that earlier but I couldn't get any output from it. It doesn't detail any of the server side code, so I was not sure how to structure output

Comment: @adeneo I tried using flushing to no avail. I have been looking at SSE but have yet found a relevant example or tutorial. If you know of any please share

Comment: So the `console.log(percentComplete)` listed in the example didn't produce anything in your console?

Comment: Just to put it out here, you can also do recursive on ajax upon success. Then have progress bar on each ajax call

Comment: @Rasclatt in the `console.log(percentComplete)` output all I get is `1` on completion of the php script

Comment: @stanley1943 Do you have any examples/tutorials of how to do this?

Comment: I suggest to store result in an array and than use json encode .. and use a loop in ajax success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all your help. I eventually managed to get this all working properly and will share exactly how I did it for anyone else's future benefit.

There are 3 files that are required - The page you are loading from, the processing script and the listening script.

You will need to know how many rows you are going to process for everything to work. I load mine from php variable `$results['total_rows'];` in loading.php

Loading.php

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            setTimeout(getProgress,1000);
            $(document).on('click','#fetch-snowfall-data a',function () {
              $(this).text('Fetching Snowfall Data...');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'process.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#response_container2").append(data);
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(getProgress,3000);
            return false;
            });
            function getProgress(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'listen.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data<=<?php echo $results['total_rows']; ?> && data>=1){
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#response_container').html('<div id="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:'+ (data / <?php echo $results["total_rows"] ?>)*100 +'%">'+ data + '/' +<?php echo $results["total_rows"] ?> +'</div></div>');
                            setTimeout(getProgress,1000);
                            console.log('Repeat');
                        } else {
                            $('#fetch-snowfall-data a').text('Fetch Snowfall Data');
                            console.log('End');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Process.php

```
foreach ( $results['resorts'] as $resort ) { 

    //Do all the things here you want to.

    $count++;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $count;
    $_SESSION['total'] = $results['total_rows'];
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
}

unset($_SESSION['progress']);
```

Listen.php

```
session_start();
echo (!empty($_SESSION['progress']) ? $_SESSION['progress'] : '');

if (!empty($_SESSION['progress']) && $_SESSION['progress'] >= $_SESSION['total']) {
    unset($_SESSION['progress']);
}
```

Some CSS for the progress bar

```
#progress {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.progress-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
    -o-transition: width .6s ease;
    transition: width .6s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by adeneo, I dont think you can return partial content. I tried to research on this before with no avail. However, if anyone can correct me, i'll be very appreciative.

The end result for me is to do recursive ajax.

javascript

```
var data = '';
$(document).on('click','#fetch-snowfall-data a',function () {
  ajaxCall(0);
});

function ajaxCall(num) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "url.php",
    data: num,
    dataType: "json",
    xhr:function(){
        //progress bar information here.
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#response_container").append(response['data']);
      if (response['check'] === 'next') {
        var nextNum = num +1;
        data += response['data'];
        ajaxCall(nextNum); //call itself for the next iteration
      }else if (response['check'] === 'done'){
        data = response['data'];
        //do stuff with the data here.
      }else if (response['check'] === 'error') {
        return response['data'];
      }
    },
    error:function(xhr, status,error){
        //error information here
    }
  });
}
```

For PHP:

Just make sure you output stuff in json with two information. `Json.check`: to see if you want to move into the next iteration, finish and output data, or report error. `Json.data` to output whatever data it needs. What you need to do is output each report at a time without `foreach` loop

--edit--

I found some topic on streaming for php

1. http://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/
2. [Best approach for (cross-platform) real-time data streaming in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495749/best-approach-for-cross-platform-real-time-data-streaming-in-php)

Comment: It is possible in coldfusion, but i'm not a php dev so no idea if it can be done with php. Look into data streaming and/or flushing the buffer.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, i'll definitely look into it. It seems like running nodejs would be better than php?

Comment: the same can be accomplished in both, so at that point it's up to personal preference. I prefer node.js