# Mimicing HTML page loaded onto an iPhone to another HTML page that could be loaded onto a desktop web browser

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble figuring this out. I have an index.html that pulls the accelerometer and gyroscope data from the iPhone and shows the changing raw data on the screen as the iPhone is moved around and changed orientation. My trouble is that I am trying to figure out how to show this changing data in another webpage for someone else to observe as I move around the iPhone. I am pretty stumped and been looking everywhere and not sure what to do. The code for index.html that I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style>
    #no {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen {
        html, body, div, span {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        body {
            height: auto;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .outer {
            background: rgba(123, 256, 245, 0.9);
            padding: 0px;
            min-height: 48px;
        }

        .box {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
            background: rgba(178,215,255,0.75);
            min-height: 160px;
        }

        .box2 {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
            background: rgba(178,215,255,0.75);
        }

        .box span {
            display: block;
        }

        span.head {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="yes">
    <div class="box" id="accel">
        <span class="head">Accelerometer</span>
        <span id="xlabel"></span>
        <span id="ylabel"></span>
        <span id="zlabel"></span>
        <span id="ilabel"></span>
        <span id="arAlphaLabel"></span>
        <span id="arBetaLabel"></span>
        <span id="arGammaLabel"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="gyro">
        <span class="head">Gyroscope</span>
        <span id="alphalabel"></span>
        <span id="betalabel"></span>
        <span id="gammalabel"></span>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="no">
    Your browser does not support Device Orientation and Motion API.
</div>

<script>

        // Position Variables
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var z = 0;

        // Speed - Velocity
        var vx = 0;
        var vy = 0;
        var vz = 0;

        // Acceleration
        var ax = 0;
        var ay = 0;
        var az = 0;
        var ai = 0;
        var arAlpha = 0;
        var arBeta = 0;
        var arGamma = 0;

        var delay = 100;
        var vMultiplier = 0.01;         var alpha = 0;

        var alpha = 0;
        var beta = 0;
        var gamma = 0;


        if (window.DeviceMotionEvent==undefined) {
            document.getElementById("no").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("yes").style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
                ax =      Math.round(Math.abs(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 1));
                ay =      Math.round(Math.abs(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * 1));
                az = Math.round(Math.abs(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z * 1));
                ai = Math.round(event.interval * 100) / 100;
                rR = event.rotationRate;
                if (rR != null) {
                    arAlpha = Math.round(rR.alpha);
                    arBeta = Math.round(rR.beta);
                        arGamma = Math.round(rR.gamma);
                }

/*
                    ax = Math.abs(event.acceleration.x * 1000);
                ay = Math.abs(event.acceleration.y * 1000);
                az = Math.abs(event.acceleration.z * 1000);
*/
            }

            window.ondeviceorientation = function(event) {
                alpha = Math.round(event.alpha);
                beta = Math.round(event.beta);
                gamma = Math.round(event.gamma);
            }

            function d2h(d) {return d.toString(16);}
            function h2d(h) {return parseInt(h,16);}



            setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("xlabel").innerHTML = "X: " + ax;
                document.getElementById("ylabel").innerHTML = "Y: " + ay;
                document.getElementById("zlabel").innerHTML = "Z: " + az;
                document.getElementById("ilabel").innerHTML = "I: " + ai;
                document.getElementById("arAlphaLabel").innerHTML = "arA: " + arAlpha;
                document.getElementById("arBetaLabel").innerHTML = "arB: " + arBeta;
                document.getElementById("arGammaLabel").innerHTML = "arG: " + arGamma;
                document.getElementById("alphalabel").innerHTML = "Alpha: " + alpha;
                document.getElementById("betalabel").innerHTML = "Beta: " + beta;
                document.getElementById("gammalabel").innerHTML = "Gamma: " + gamma;



            }, delay);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: How is the iPhone loading index.html?  Is it served by a local server on your network, or is it phonegapped into an app, or...?

Comment: Check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495749/best-approach-for-cross-platform-real-time-data-streaming-in-php)

Comment: So basically the index.html is published on azure and when loaded onto iphone the data gets pulled from the iphone through the ondevicemotion